# transforming data to the service class android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, service, android-notifications

I m trying to build a music player app so when the music is played ,the service should start where a notification will be shown so I m trying to send using an intent from the activity class to the service class but when and the problem is that only one data is restored .
for this process I used the code below

in the main activity

> 

```
public void startService(int i,ArrayList<String> l) {
>         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
>         serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", musicfileslist.get(i));
>         serviceIntent.putExtra("msg",msg);
>         serviceIntent.putExtra("i",i);
> 
>      
>         ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
> 
>  }
```

in the serviceclass

```
> String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
>         String msg=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
>         int i=intnt.getIntExtra("i",0);
```

only input is restored and the other are all null
please tell me what is the problem here

Comment: I would first check if the values are correct when you put them into the intent. It's possible the values are null. Either set breakpoints or use logs to confirm if the values are ok.

Comment: yes ,I m sure that they are not null

Comment: What type is `msg` in the method `startService()`? Is this defined as `String`?

Comment: yes ,it is and i is int

Comment: You should add debug logging and log all the "extras" that are in the `Intent` on arrival in the service. You can do that by iterating over `intent.getExtras().keySet()` and call `intent.getExtras.get(key)` on each element in the returned key set and output the key and the returned value. This should tell you what is in the extras bundle.